# how to check if 2 fields are equal in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular4-forms

i am developing a application in angular 4. there i have a small form. validations are working fine. but i want to verify that both passwords and the password confirm fields are same.

```
    registerUser = this.fb.group({
     name: new FormControl(this.data.name, Validators.required),
     email: new FormControl({value: this.data.email, disabled: true}, [ 
            Validators.required,
            Validators.email,
            this.valdaitionService.emailDomainValidator
        ]),
     emailp: new FormControl(this.data.emailp,Validators.email),
     designation:new FormControl({value: this.data.designation, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
     empType:new FormControl({value: this.data.empType, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
     mobileNo:new FormControl(this.data.mobileNo, [Validators.required]), 
     year:new FormControl({value: this.data.year, disabled: true}, [Validators.required]), 
     month:new FormControl({value: this.data.month, disabled: true}, [Validators.required]),    
     password: new FormControl("", []),  
     passwordc: new FormControl("", []),  


  });
```

is there a way in angular for form control that i can verify both password and passwordc fields are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement your custom validator directive.
I assume you did similar job on "this.valdaitionService.emailDomainValidator).

For your reference please check the link below:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

```
registerUser = this.fb.group({
                 name: new FormControl(this.data.name, Validators.required),
                 email: new FormControl({value: this.data.email, disabled: true}, [ 
                        Validators.required,
                        Validators.email,
                        this.valdaitionService.emailDomainValidator
                    ]),
                 emailp: new FormControl(this.data.emailp,Validators.email),
                 designation:new FormControl({value: this.data.designation, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
                 empType:new FormControl({value: this.data.empType, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
                 mobileNo:new FormControl(this.data.mobileNo, [Validators.required]), 
                 year:new FormControl({value: this.data.year, disabled: true}, [Validators.required]), 
                 month:new FormControl({value: this.data.month, disabled: true}, [Validators.required]),    
                 password: new FormControl("", []),  
                 passwordc: new FormControl("", []),  
            {
                  validator: this.MatchConfirom('passwordc','passwordc'),
                }

              });


          private MatchConfirom(type1: any, type2: any) {

            return (checkForm: FormGroup) => {
              let value1 = checkForm.controls[type1];
              let value2 = checkForm.controls[type2];


              if (value1.value === value2.value ) {
                return value2.setErrors(null);
              } else {
                return value2.setErrors({ notEquivalent: true });
              }
            };
          }
Here MatchConfirom(pass1,pass2) is match function which passes two parameter password & confirom password.it calls inside formgroup instance. if both password is correct than setErrors is true for value instance otherwise false.
```